# How to take a screenshot of login screen

Tags: 22.04, login-screen, screenshot

I want to take screenshot of **login screen** in **ubuntu 22.04.1**.

Comment: A person who has not logged in would not have write permissions nor access to the clipboard. The only way (that I know of) to get a screenshot of the login screen is to use a VM and take a screenshot of the VM's login screen 

Comment: Is there any commands so I can try from the terminal?

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment, not that I am aware of. Taking a screenshot requires data to be copied, either to memory or to the storage device. This requires permission. A person who is at the login screen does not have permission to store data to memory (as it makes no sense to) or to the disk (as this would be a security vulnerability).

Comment: @matigo thank you.